# S-grammar for this regular expression

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

Given this regular expression:

$r = a a^* b + b^* c b$

I think this is the simple grammar, but I was getting a little lost with the productions:

$S \rightarrow S_1 | S_2$

$S_1 \rightarrow a A b$

$A \rightarrow a A | a$

$S_2 \rightarrow b S_2 | c b$

Comment: Try cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Not quite, your grammar won't accept $ab$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $r = a a^* b + b^* c b = (a a^*  + b^* c )b$, then write a production for each 'component':

$S \rightarrow P b$

$P \rightarrow Q_1 | Q_2 $

$Q_1 \rightarrow a | Q_1 a$

$Q_2 \rightarrow c | b Q_2 $

Comment: Thanks yes didn't realize I was missing $a b$